# Firebase Functions - getting a 403 Forbidden error after deploying my functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am just getting started with Firebase Functions. I have tested successfully using the emulator suite and see my function working well. However, when deploying my function and trying to access the generated URL for my function, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

I checked Google Cloud IAM console and see that my current account is set as the Owner role for the function, but I also added the "Cloud Functions Admin" role as well.

Despite these permissions, I am still seeing the 403 Forbidden errors when trying to access my function.

I do not wish to make my function public, though I did perform a test with public access enabled and I was able to access my function and it ran successfully. I revoked the public access after this test, though, and would prefer to keep the function private. Most answers I see to this question simply say to open the function up for public access by setting the "allUsers" member to have the "invoke cloud functions" role.

I am not sure what else to try. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access directly the Cloud/Firebase Function that requires authentication if it doesn't have a [login authentication or verifying identity of the users](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) inside your function, it means you need to build/codes a function for it.

You can test your Cloud Function using `curl` via CLI but you will use the `gcloud auth print-identity-token` for authentication, example:

```
curl https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME \
  -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
```

To access your Cloud/Firebase Function you can integrate [Google Sign-In with Firebase Authentication](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/authorized-https-endpoint) and there are a lot of example and explanation in Stack Overflow how you can access your Cloud/Firebase Function that requires an authentication, it will depend on your case:

1. [Callable Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64382133/8753991)
2. [Generate Token(google-auth-library)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66614078/8753991)
3. [from `firebase-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44500591/8753991)
4. [Another example of Cloud Function with Firebase Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59230871/8753991)
5. [Limit access to your Cloud Function Answer/Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315013/8753991)
6. [Background Information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66814095/8753991)